# error when invoking Activator.CreateInstance with IEnumerable parameter filtered with LINQ

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, dependency-injection, reflection

tl;dr:
When I filter output of `ServiceProvider.GetServices(Type)` for some reason I cannot use it later for constructing object with reflection. What am I missing?

**Edit**: Maybe what I am trying here is not the way. I want to be able to create `SomeService<Message>` with different collections of handlers. Suppose all handlers are: A,B,C and D then one instance of SomeService should have handlers A and B, but second instance should use C and D.

Complete console application with DependencyInjection as its only dependency:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace GenericsExperiment
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //setup DI
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddTransient<ISomeHandler<Message>, MessageHandler>();
            services.AddTransient<ISomeHandler<Message>, MessageHandler2>();
            var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            //get all types of ISomeHandler<Message>
            var messageType = typeof(Message);
            var handlerType = typeof(ISomeHandler<>);
            var handlerGenericType = handlerType.MakeGenericType(messageType);
            var handlers = serviceProvider.GetServices(handlerGenericType);

            //Create SomeService type and pass handlers to constructor
            var someServiceType = typeof(SomeService<>);
            var someServiceGenericType = someServiceType.MakeGenericType(messageType);
            var concreteService = Activator.CreateInstance(someServiceGenericType,
                handlers) as SomeService<Message>;
            Console.WriteLine("Concrete type with all handlers created");


            //same as above but this time use primitive filtering:
            var filteredHandlers = serviceProvider.GetServices(handlerGenericType)
                .Where(h => h.GetType().FullName.Contains("MessageHandler2")).ToList();

            //this line throws exception System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type
            //'GenericsExperiment.SomeService`1[[GenericsExperiment.Message, GenericsExperiment,
            //Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' not found.
            var concreteServiceWithFilteredHandlers = Activator.CreateInstance(someServiceGenericType,
                filteredHandlers) as SomeService<Message>;

        }
    }

    public class Message { public string Value { get; set; } }

    public interface ISomeHandler<in T> {
        void Handle(T message);
    }

    public class MessageHandler : ISomeHandler<Message> {
        public void Handle(Message message)=>Console.WriteLine($"handled: {message.Value}");
    }

    public class MessageHandler2 : ISomeHandler<Message> {
        public void Handle(Message message) => Console.WriteLine($"handled by messageHandler 2: {message.Value}");
    }

    public class SomeService<T> where T : class {
        public SomeService(IEnumerable<ISomeHandler<T>> handlers) { }

        public void DoSomethingWithHandlers() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to supply a `List<object>` to a constructor that requires an `IEnumerable<ISomeHandler<Message>>`. That is impossible, which can be checked by writing a hard-coded example:

```cs
new SomeService<Message>(filteredHandlers);
```

This results in the following C# compile error:

> CS1503    Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<GenericsExperiment.ISomeHandler<GenericsExperiment.Message>>'

Working with generic types and reflection is a b*tch, which is why DI Containers can come in very handy. If you register `SomeService<T>` in the DI Container and resolve it from the container, all this complexity is abstracted for you:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<ISomeHandler<Message>, MessageHandler>();
services.AddTransient<ISomeHandler<Message>, MessageHandler2>();
services.AddTransient(typeof(SomeService<>), typeof(SomeService<>));
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var service = serviceProvider.GetService<SomeService<Message>>();

service.DoSomethingWithHandlers();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am aware that it all could be done with DI, this is simplified example, however my main goal is to be able to create instances with different collections of same type handlers . What is more I don't know the type I am creating at compile time hence GetService(Type) instead of generic method.

Comment: It is of course possible to achieve this without a DI Container; those containers are mostly written in C# anyway; but you will have to convert (not cast) the collection, which will likely involve calling `Enumerable.OfType<T>` using reflection or some similar construct.